# How can I know to which element a thread of my android app is related?

Tags: android, multithreading

First of all, I don't create threads manually.

I can monitor the threads of my android app :

[image]

How can I know to which elements these threads are related ?

For example all the httpXX threads or AsyncTask #X , is there a way to know where they're created in the code? Because they stay there everytime and I'm afraid to leak the memory.

In opposition I have an ImageCache that load images in threads. These thread appear in the list when I'm in the view that display the images and disappear when I close the app.

httpX , AsyncTask #X , WebViewWorkerThread , etc DON'T disappear when I close the app. So I'd like to know where I can free the memory, close connections, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This threads are created by Android classes which internally rely on thread pools. The main idea of thread pool is not to create a new thread every time when you need to do something but reuse already started threads and keep them running even if there is no work for them now.

For example `AsyncTask #X` threads are created by [AsyncTask](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) internal `ThreadPoolExecutor`. If you look into it's source code you will notice this ThreadFactory:

```
private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};
```

`WebViewCoreThread`, `WebViewWorkerThread`, and `http0` - `http11` are internal worker threads of `WebView` which executes all operations concerning loading html data over the network, processing, etc. on behalf of `WebView`.

So all this threads are managed by Android system and you don't need to do anything with them. And it's all right that they don't disappear when you close your app.